# UIButton customized to use standard image/color for highlighted state

Tags: iphone, uibutton

For one of UIButton on a view, I created an image to use for normal state, but I want to keep using the default blue color/image for the highlighted/selected state, is there a way to do that? Or do I really have to prepare customized image for the highlighted/selected as well?

The following is the code that I have per @mashios request and suggestion below -

```
UIButton *shareButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[shareButton setFrame:CGRectMake(1.0, 0.0, 99.0, 43.0)];
[shareButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_normal"] 
                                 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 
                                 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[shareButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_normal"] // bottom_up_left_3_selected
                                 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 
                                 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(share:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set same image to both state.

Comment: I just experimented doing that by setting the same image (used for normal state) to the highlighted state as well. The result is not what I wanted but instead there is no color change at all when tap on the button.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you wanted same image for normal,highlighted and selected state. In another comment you wanted to change color of button. Although I wanted to suggest you few thing.
1. At the time of set the images to button pls. pass full string of image name like (something.jpg).
2. Use stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth & topCapHeight only if required.
3. Set the image like this [[shareButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_normal.jpg/png"]forcontrolstate:UIControlStateNormal];
4. I just change these things and it worked for me.